# Dockerfile for tesseract 4.0

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tesseract

I am trying to create a Dockerfile for `tesseract-ocr` version 4.0.
Following are the contents of the Docker file.

```bash
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties- 
  common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr

FROM python:3.6-alpine
ADD . /App
WORKDIR /App
COPY requirements.txt ./ 
COPY . . 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

I am able to build the Docker image, but when I spin a container and try to run a `tesseract` command, I get

> "tesseract" not found

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04:

```bash
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install tesseract-ocr -y \
    python3 \
    #python-setuptools \
    python3-pip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove

ADD . /home/App
WORKDIR /home/App
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

VOLUME ["/data"]
EXPOSE 5000 5000
CMD ["python3","OCRRun.py"]
```

Comment: Is this solution still valid for tesseract?